# PHP PEAR GoogleMapsAPI DB Error: not found

Tags: php, database, pear

I am running a LAMP server for my development environment on Ubuntu 11.10.

I installed pear's DB (I know its deprecated, but this Google maps API class requires it)...

I have installed it, but now every time I try to load this "HelloWorld" map I'm testing on, I get an error message DB Error: not found.

I checked my dsn string and it looks good, I changed the database table to the correct table I am using, etc.

Apache error log doesn't report anything for this problem.

Has anybody run into a similar problem, or have any ideas what the problem could be?

If you need to see any code, I'll post it...

Answer (score 0):

The database driver you're using cannot be found. Check if you're using the correct one.